# GCC 4.5/Ubuntu 11.04 is auto-threading code?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction, mpi

I apologize ahead of time that I don't quite have the proper jargon to describe my problem, and that I have likely not given enough information.

I've been running my MPI code under gcc 4.4 and OpenMPI/MPICH2 for months now with no issue on a variety of platforms. Recently I upgrade a set of servers and my desktop to Ubuntu 11.04 (running gcc 4.5 now) and ran an 8 task job on a node with 8 processors. Typically I see nearly 100% user CPU utilization, and now I see only 60% user CPU and over 30% system cpu. This leads to a remarkable slowdown of my code when run in this fashion.

Investigating further, I simply ran a serial job, and noted that the process reported 150+% cpu time was being used. So, my program was multithreading itself over many processors. I verified this explicitly using 'ps -eLF' and looking at the per-processor loads.

This is an incredibly bad and inefficient thing for my MPI code, and I have no idea where it comes from. Nothing has changed other than the move to Ubuntu 11.04 and gcc 4.5. I have verified this against varying OpenMPI versions.

I also moved binaries around between two binary-compatible machines. If I compile on another machine (ubuntu 10.10/gcc 4.4) and run there, everything is fine. Moving the binary to the Ubuntu 11.04 machine, the same binary begins threading itself.

It is worth noting that I have explicitly disabled all optimizations (-O0), thinking my default (-O3) could include something I didn't understand in 4.5. I get identical behavior regardless of the optimization level.

Please let me know what further information I can provide to determine the source of this problem.

*** ADDITIONAL INFO ***

Results of ldd  in response to request. Simply, it's OpenMPI, libconfig, and scalapack, along with standard gcc stuff:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffffd95d000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f2bd206a000)
libconfig.so.8 => /usr/lib/libconfig.so.8 (0x00007f2bd1e60000)
libscalapack-openmpi.so.1 => /usr/lib/libscalapack-openmpi.so.1 (0x00007f2bd151c000)
libmpi.so.0 => /usr/lib/libmpi.so.0 (0x00007f2bd126b000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f2bd0ed7000)
libblacsCinit-openmpi.so.1 => /usr/lib/libblacsCinit-openmpi.so.1 (0x00007f2bd0cd4000)
libblacs-openmpi.so.1 => /usr/lib/libblacs-openmpi.so.1 (0x00007f2bd0aa4000)
libblas.so.3gf => /usr/lib/libblas.so.3gf (0x00007f2bd022f000)
liblapack.so.3gf => /usr/lib/liblapack.so.3gf (0x00007f2bcf639000)
libmpi_f77.so.0 => /usr/lib/libmpi_f77.so.0 (0x00007f2bcf406000)
libgfortran.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.3 (0x00007f2bcf122000)
libopen-rte.so.0 => /usr/lib/libopen-rte.so.0 (0x00007f2bceed3000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f2bcecb5000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f2bd22fc000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f2bcea9f000)
libopen-pal.so.0 => /usr/lib/libopen-pal.so.0 (0x00007f2bce847000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f2bce643000)
libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f2bce43f000)
```

All the best.

Comment: What libraries are used by you code? Can you show results of `ldd your_programme` for serial version?

Comment: sure. it's MPI, libconfig, and scalapack. i have added the results of ldd to the main post. each of these libraries i have used from the apt repositories and built them custom on both platforms (the good 4.4 and bad 4.5 platforms). nothing seems to change anything about the behavior.

Comment: i realized that results was for the parallel version. i never build a serial version, MPI is baked in. you'll notice lots of other stuff there, the on that concerns me most is libpthread even though my makefile never explicitly links that library, so i should see where things like that come from. however, if i take this binary, compiled in gcc 4.5 with these libraries, and run it on a binary-compatible ubuntu 10.10 install, everything performs as expected. all with the same libraries. it's truly odd.

Comment: try to do an `strace -f` of odd version or even an ltrace -S

Comment: done. is there something in particular you'd be looking for here? the outputs are fairly massive, understandably. as a first pass, i grepped through for threads and scalapack and found identical open statments.

Comment: well, i did a lot of exhaustive testing by enabling and disabling various subsystems of my code, and it's now clear that the problem lies in the scalapack library built by ubuntu in 11.04, which, seemingly identical to that in 10.10, does some really wacky things it shouldn't for an MPI build of that library. it is performing as if it had PVM/shared memory support. this is a serious error in that build in  ubuntu 11.04. the key was your ltrace, where i found numerous calls to SYS_clone after scalapack functions were called.

Comment: On a sidenote: If you build a pipeline on unix-like systems, the kernel may parallelize that, e.g. `find | grep meh` may warm up more than one CPU.

Answer (score 1):

is it possible that you are running into this feature? http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/parallel_mode.html

basically, certain standard library routines have parallel implementations.However, it is only turned on when the `_GLIBCXX_PARALLEL` macro is defined.

Comment: this program is written entirely in C, not C++, and i'm not using anything available in C1X, etc. everything is strict C99. certainly i have not defined such a macro.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing 60%/40% doesn't tell anything, perhaps the processing is just accounted differently. The only interesting figure here would be to compare the wallclock time of the total execution of your code.

Also, I would think that (if so) it is not your binary itself that is parallelized but the MPI libaries. To check that you would not only have to compile your code on the other machine but also to link it statically. Only then you can be sure that you run exactly the same binary code in all of its aspects on the other machine.

Then, also you can't be sure that the MPI library doesn't use C++ under the hood. I remember that it was quite difficult for one of the MPI libs (don't remember which) to convice to not to compile against the C++ interface, even if you were only doing C.

Comment: The processing is not accounted for differently. There is a very obvious slowdown in the code itself. Running 8 tasks is less than half the speed on Ubuntu 11.04 than in 10.10.

I find it hard to believe that a system designed for explicit non-shared-memory parallelization would thread out copies of my code, even when run **without** MPI, as in the serial case I mention in my original post. Identical MPI versions were compiled by me in an identical fashion on both platforms with no effect. The apt repository version of MPI yields the same behavior.

Comment: This would have been an interesting information you could have given in your question.

Comment: I will add this information to the original post as you suggest.